# How to mount NTFS drive at startup

Tags: dual-boot, automount, ntfs, fstab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

I'm not even sure if this is the right question, but basically I have a partition with Windows 7 on it (named Acer in my Ubuntu places menu) that I have to click on every time I start the computer in order for my music to come up in Rhythmbox, since my music is stored on the windows drive. What I want to do is have the NTFS drive "Acer" mount automatically when I start the computer, so my music is there automatically.

Comment: Obtain the UUID of the disk and add it to the /etc/fstab as demonstrated in this [tutorial](https://bit.ly/2Ur9XZY).