# How to add NTFS partition to fstab?

Tags: wine, mount, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount NTFS drive at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup)

I need to run `.exe` files on my Vista partition but I can't give them the right permissions so I need a way of auto mounting with the full permissions in order to run any files I need, otherwise I have to manually mount it each time I need it.

Comment: @kar: It would be except this is an extension of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail/18053#18053) answer and the details are a bit different I think.

Answer (score 6):

In order to do this, you'll need to edit `/etc/fstab`.

1. Make a backup of the file with the following command:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old
   ```
2. Now open the file with gedit:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
3. At the bottom, add the following:

   ```
   /dev/sda1 /media/vista/ ntfs fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
   ```
4. Restart and make sure that it is now mounted when you log in.

Answer (score 4):

- Install [**ntfs-config**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ntfs-config) [image: Install ntfs-config]
- After installation you can access it under **System > Administration > NTFS Configuration Tool**.
- Select the appropriate drive you want to get mounted.

  [image]

Also see this **[post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup)**.

Comment: what theme is that (will delete comment on answer :P)

Comment: @Roland-Taylor thats tropical :)