# Why doesn't Banshee play music from another filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, banshee, ntfs

I have all my music in all partitions; so that Windows Vista has one, Ubuntu has one and my music, videos and more have one and so that the operating systems have their music video whatever on the same location.

But every time I reboot Ubuntu again and I want to hear music via Banshee, it insists on searching in  "Username/music" folder instead of the folder I have selected countless times. Is this because the files are on another partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the files are on another partition. Which is NTFS partition.
When you add songs from this partition to Banshee,you need to mount it every time you log in, so Banshee can access the songs and play them.

And by mounting a partition, you just need to click on it every time you log in:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The partition does not auto mount so when Banshee is going to place a song, you double click on it and nothing happens. Just mount the partition and double click again the song, it should play. To **auto mount a NTFS partition correctly** please use the answers provide in the following questions:

1 - [How to add NTFS partition to fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18067/how-to-add-ntfs-partition-to-fstab)
2. [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)
3. [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-partition)

With this 3 you will know how to mount, auto-mount and set permissions to the NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing (mounting the NTFS partition every time) and sometimes forgetting and wondering why isn't Banshee playing my songs. So I edited `/etc/fstab` to auto-mount the partition. Just remember to mount it with the same name (or else you would need to reconfigure your Banshee Library)

Instructions for fstab : [Fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

**UPDATE**: Here are some detailed instructions:

1. Open a terminal (Press Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Type `blkid`. The output will contain one line for each partition. Find the line pertaining to your NTFS partition. Note down the `/dev/sda2` part (where 2 may differ)
3. now type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` to edit your fstab file. This file is the one that mounts partitions automatically.
4. Add a new line reading `/dev/sda2 /media/Entertainment`

Just remember to replace /dev/sda2 with your own parition name and Entertainment with your own partition label.

Comment: Ehm, im pretty new to ubuntu, can you explain how to do it step by step? I goes a little over my level of skils im afraid :$