# Windows mounting point

Tags: windows, mount, fstab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount NTFS drive at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup)

Is there any way to specify the mounting point of the windows partition(/dev/sda2 in this case) and make it mount on startup?