# Can I permanently mount a Windows Drive in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, mount, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

I am new to Ubuntu. I have 2 internal HDDs in my PC. One with Ubuntu and the other has Windows Vista on it. I have all my music and pictures etc. on my Vista drive. I want to set up Ubuntu so that I can run music players and pic viewers on those directories in Vista without having to make duplicate copies of the files on my Ubuntu drive. I'm hoping there is a way to permanently mount a drive so that when I log into Ubuntu it will treat that vista FS as permanent so when I open up a photo viewer I dont have to re-upload the files directories every time I boot into Ubuntu.

I mounted the Vista drive with the mount command but when I shut my PC off and then turned it on again, the direc where I mounted the drive (/media/c) was empty.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks a lot,
Nathan

Comment: Search for things related to 'NTFS' and 'fstab'. cosmix searched for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have already been answered on askubuntu several times. Please read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions) and perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup). They both cover most of the things anyone would tell you about mounting your Windows partition on boot, the first one being a bit more detailed.

Comment: So I did the fstab method. I went in and added the line of code, then I went and created the directory for the mount point at /media/Win_Drive and then I typed sudo mount -a and it worked.. I shut off computer and restart it.  I get an error saying "Found serious errors when trying to mount drive a /media/Win_Drive. I hit S to skip mounting and then go in and type sudo mount -a and it mounts fine. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: It's probably your fstab line. Check out https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+question/175474