# How to Automatically run two commands after login?

Tags: startup, command-line, init.d

I have these two commands that I need to manually run every time after login:

```
autossh -M 2000 -N -f -q -D 127.0.0.1:7070 user@domain.com
```

and

```
sudo mkdir /media/C
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/C
```

I'd like to make them automatically run every time I boot and login to my computer. I'm currently using 10.04LTS.

BTW, I only vaguely know what `init.d` or `runlevel` mean. But I still prefer to know a command-line based way to achieve this, not a fancy GUI way. Also, the `autossh` will only succeed after Ubuntu automatically detect and connect to my network, so should we let it retry infinitely until successfully executed?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your question to explain why you're mounting manually instead of adding it to /etc/fstab?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: I don't have any particular reason. fstab seems a viable option but I don't quite understand how to do it.

Comment: add startup app with command: `autossh -M 2000 -N -f -q -D 127.0.0.1:7070 user@domain.com && sudo mkdir /media/C && sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/C`

Answer (score 9):

- Create a script file, e.g. named `my_file.sh`, in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory.
- Put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.
- Write whatever command(s) you want to be executed immediately after logging in, e.g. `pgrep udhcpd`.
- Mark your file as executable: `chmod +x /etc/profile.d/my_file.sh`

*It should get executed after login. In case it doesn't or you don't have the ability to use root privileges, creating the same file under `~/.config/autostart` should work fine (I haven't tried this directory before).

Comment: Startup programs were not working for me as I lost one specific setting at every login. After adding the command to `/etc/profile.d/` directory, it's now working as it should. This should definitely be picked as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Adding the autossh Command

1. On the panel select `System` --> `Preferences` --> `Startup Applications`.
2. Under the `Startup Programs` tab select the `Add` button.
3. Choose any Name you want and paste in your command (the Comment is optional)
4. Click the `Add` button.

#### Note for newer versions of Ubuntu

You can find this application by searching for "Startup Applications" in the dash. Also,
you can always launch it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (or opening a terminal) and running `gnome-session-properties`.

[image: Add Startup Program]

## Mounting the Partition

### Option 1: Add partition to `/etc/fstab`

- See [How to mount NTFS drive at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/9599/3780) if it is a Windows partition.
- [Ubuntu Community Fstab documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

### Option 2: Use `udisks`

Add this startup command as shown previously:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda2
```

Comment: thank you! But can you point out how to achieve the first task in a non-GUI way? For the second, thank you for letting me know but I wonder if there's any disadvantage when just doing a `mkdir` and a `mount`.

Comment: Can't find this screen on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @ruda.almeida see the changes I made to the post.

Comment: Thanks! My copy of Ubuntu is not in English, so I had a hard time finding it. Thanks for taking your time to expand this answer!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you got it working.