# Back up from windows to ubuntu

Tags: backup

I've recently installed Ubuntu along side of win7 on a netbook. I want to back up all my information from Windows, so I can switch to Ubuntu only.

Any advice?

Comment: your question is not clear as to what information you are speaking of.. are you talking your documents and specific files and folders ? please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into this answer if your Windows partition doesn't automatically mount itself in Ubuntu.

[How to mount NTFS drive at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup)

Once it is mounted, drag and drop your files to Ubuntu and then erase Windows. Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's basically as easy as clicking on the windows file system on your file manager(it should automatically mount itself), locating your files, and draggin them over to your corresponding directories in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Did you back-up your Windows data anywhere before installing Ubuntu (on a flash drive or on another machine, maybe)?  If so, you can just copy it from there to your Ubuntu partition.  Otherwise, your Windows partition *should* be visible from within your file manager.

And by the way, it's a good idea to back-up your data anytime you're messing with your disk partitions or installing another OS (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Well although it isn't an usual backup method, if you have a fairly recent computer that supports hardware virtualization,you might want to consider making what is called a P2V copy of your windows installation.

What this does is create a virtualized copy of your entire physical windows installation that you can then replay for inside a VM player/manager software.

And yes both the P2V converter and the VM player software are free,although not opensource.

So first thing you need to do is go into windows and install the converter from this address http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

(Click on download and log into your account or create one just for that)
 When you're done downloading and installing run the standalone converter and choose *powered-on Machine* and *this local machine* as the source,then click *next*.

At the next screen select vmware workstation as the machine type and select also vmware workstation 8.x as the product.. Then give it the location of an external hard drive to which send the copy to when doing the conversion.

Then click next twice and go do something else for a while.. It can take a few hours to copy all your data to an external hard drive.
When this step is done you can shutdown and reboot into ubuntu.

In ubuntu you now have to install the vmware player from this page http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html

Yes virtualbox is great but i don't know if a vmware machine can be used from it.
There are ways most probably,but it is beyond the scope of my answer.

Now you can run the vmware player and open the VM you have on your external drive.
You can then proceed to copy files from your VM to your ubuntu desktop and see how to delete your old windows partition.