# How to "LOCK" D: to my launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

How to "LOCK" D: to my launcher?

I am not getting option in right-click menu to lock it over LAUNCHER.
Please Help.

Comment: What is D: ? I do not understand this syntax.

Comment: What is D:?. Are you talking about windows?

Comment: sorry for it.. 
yes it's d: in my windows..

Comment: It's D drive in windows.. a partition...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "lock" partitions to the launcher in that way. To have it always appear, you would need to configure it to be automounted on boot, or when you log in. Your question is however, also a duplicate of I think, [How to mount NTFS drive at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup).

Comment: But I had locked them before updating ubuntu12.04..then why not now?

Comment: Just try to use Fstab as demonstrated to auto-mount and then *make* a launcher to the mount point.

Comment: no.i dont want to auto mount it..