# How to mount ntfs partitions on startup?

Tags: mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

I now this question has been asked a million times but this is a bit different, now I need to know on how to mount it on ubuntu 12.10
I been using PYSDM for a long time but on ubuntu 12.10 it does not work sadly, I installed arios-automount and it mounted partitions on start up but problem i have with it, on start up it launches all the partition window

So can anyone tell me a good mount manager for ubuntu 12.10 with graphical user interface

thank you for your time

Answer (score 13):

You can edit the /etc/fstab file to mount partitions at boot time. That's the traditional method.

Use Alt-Ctrl-T to start a terminal. Create a mount point with `sudo mkdir /media/ntfs`. then use `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` and enter a line for the mount you want.

Here's one for my ntfs partition:

```
UUID=CA009B90009B825D /media/ntfs ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,allow_other 0 0
```

You will have to specify your own UUID. You can find these by entering the command:

```
sudo blkid
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but i am looking for graphical user interface way

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup