# How to create a permanent link to your Windows desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, directory, accessibility

I want to have a way to easily access the desktop of my Windows user account from my Ubuntu account on my dual-booted machine.

Of course, I can easily create a link on my Ubuntu desktop to the path in my windows file system, however, this link is reported as broken after restarting Ubuntu. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mount Windows partition at startup. How to do that, you can read here:

[How to mount ntfs partitions on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204140/how-to-mount-ntfs-partitions-on-startup)

and here:

[How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: Hey Sebastian, just wanted to report back that your answer was of course the right solution to my problem and I could setup the automount easily with the resource you have given. Many thanks!