# Cant Resume Torrent Downloads After Restarting the PC

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, qbittorrent, torrent-client

I was trying to download big files from torrent 
In my place the electricity is gone off for 2- 3 hours every 24 hour , which will interrupt my torrent download .

On windows torrent when I turn on my PC when  the electricity comes and it complete the download , On Ubuntu it just give and error and restart the download from the beginning.

I tried more than file all the same . I tried 3 Ubuntu torrent clients they all cant resume the download transmission say that it cant locate the files , **qbitroent** gives this error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDpS1.png]

Please help me i so confused this is the 3 time id re download this film.

Comment: Your problem is not related to torrent software but to the location where you are trying to save the files into. Are you, for instance, trying to save these files into an external drive? Or are you trying to save them to some place outside your home folder?

Comment: I'm regularly using Transmission and never had problems resuming. Could you open a terminal and `ls -al ~/path/to/downloading-part-file` and give us the output?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa i'm saving them on my HDD partition D: the system is on partition c: no im not using external drives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you have it then: you must first mount that drive and only then open your torrent client. To be sure the drive is mounted you can simply navigate there with your file browser.

You might also want to set that drive to mount automatically at startup:

[How to make hdd's mount at startup in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-hdds-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: seems that's the problem , ill try it next time , thank a lot buddy , appreciate your help guys ...

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same Problem. The solutions given about requires lots of steps and I guess will solve the problem permanently. A temporary fix that worked for me is to do the following steps.
When computer is  restarted, the error message appears.

1. Open the qBittorrent
2. Right click on the file you were downloading click on `set location`
3. Browse to the location where the file was originally located and set the location.

Thats it. The download resumes from where it stopped and not from the beginning. It's just a temporary fix you have to do this everytime you restart your system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried another bit torrent alternative?

From my experience, [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) is the best gnome client on Ubuntu. Its supposed to come pre-installed in Ubuntu so you should it if you search for it.

I am fairly certain that tranmission should have an option to automatically resume torrents on startup. There should also be an option to allow it to start up on login.

Comment: yes bro i had already tried tranmstion and i had mentioned that in the question " transmission say that it cant locate the files" , but the same it cant resume ...

Comment: Oh, how about you your question then? The grammar makes it seem like your referring to a "download transmission" rather than the actual client. Are you download your torrents to an external drive?

Comment: Sorry English in not my main language , no im using the internal HDD but in another partition other that the system

Comment: Well then thats probably what is wrong. You need to make sure the partition is mounted before you can start. Have you edited fstab to  auto-mount the partition for downloads? You can also use the Ubuntu [Disk Management Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) for setting this up if you prefer a GUI.