# Error when copying a file to an NTFS volume

Tags: files

I have a folder in `/media/li`. I want to copy and paste the files into that folder.

```
li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/media/li$ ls -ltr
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 11 li li 16384 Dec 31  1969  DELLRESTORE
drwxrwxrwx  1 li li  4096 Oct 19 20:58 'New Volume'
```

It said:

> Error while copying "question.doc".
>
> Error opening file "/media/li/New Volume/question.doc": No such file
>   or directory

[image]

[image]

```
$ cat /etc/mtab | grep 'li'
/dev/sdb2 /media/li/New\040Volume fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

~$ sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop



Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2      264192 2228799487 2228535296     1T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  2228799488 2287396863   58597376    28G Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  2287396864 3263963135  976566272 465.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5  3263963136 3283499007   19535872   9.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb6  3283499008 4260065279  976566272 465.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb7  4260065280 4455380991  195315712  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb8  4455380992 4457338879    1957888   956M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb9  4457338880 4458319871     980992   479M EFI System
/dev/sdb10 4458319872 7814035455 3355715584   1.6T Linux filesystem



li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/media/li$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /media/li -o rw,permissions
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.


li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/media/li$ sudo mount New\ Volume
mount: New Volume: can't find in /etc/fstab.

li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/media/li$ ls
 360SANDBOX                hp                pagefile.sys    'Program       Files (x86)'   SWSetup                      Windows
bootTel.dat               inetpub           PerfLogs         Recovery               SYSTEM.SAV                  '$WINDOWS.~BT'
'Documents and Settings'   Intel             ProgramData     '$RECYCLE.BIN'         'System Volume Information'
 hiberfil.sys              IntelOptaneData  'Program Files'   swapfile.sys           Users

li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/media/li$ touch /media/li/New\ Volume
touch: cannot touch '/media/li/New Volume': Read-only file system
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=ca31db48-1c16-47bf-95db-b37e59b2954e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=39757d5a-5bd3-450c-a4ae-c6d96b04c040 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb9 during installation
UUID=2591-F4D4  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb10 during installation
UUID=04c65089-71ff-4b33-9a30-c21b8c77eda2 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /tmp was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=a66a7593-7e4f-49e9-bbe2-0c64b075bceb /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /usr was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=d6442eb1-3b8d-4c48-8fe6-26e0f7bf93d4 /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=e25f78e5-bbef-48b3-852c-89c5b44b071f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: show: `cat /etc/mtab`, `cat /etc/fstab`, `sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop`

Comment: 'New Volume' NEQ _New Volume_ the names differ,

Comment: @K7AAY that's likely just the default `--quoting-style`. See for example [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: @steeldriver More likely a spelling corrector; ^D  volumn without the "e"

Comment: Updated answer. Please, try

Comment: It looks like you've mounted your Windows C: drive at that mount point. First, let me warn you... mounting the C: drive, and then modifying it from Ubuntu, may cause real Windows problems. That said, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you so much for your kindly help!  I have already updated. Thank you again and really appreciated your great help! yueli

Comment: @Gryu, Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I can not get into the windows system right now. It is always repair. Thank you again and really appreciated any of your great help! yueli

Comment: @Gryu,Thank you for your help!  Please see updated my question. Really appreciated! yueli

Comment: Try to find Windows live cd, boot with it and try disabling cache. I could not chek now if it is possible, but you could try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not access partition after mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411732/can-not-access-partition-after-mounting)

Comment: @karel, Thank you for your suggestion! Right now, I can access partition after mounting, but I can not get into the windows system. Thank you again!

Comment: @Gryu, Thank you so much for your great help! Even I press F10, to get into the boot system, let it boot from window, it still said: preparing automatic repair, diagnosing your PC. Thank yo again!

Comment: F10 is the key for accessing the BIOS on HP Pavilion laptops, so it seems that you are getting a "preparing automatic repair, diagnosing your PC" error message when trying to boot Windows from BIOS. Based on this assumption I suggest taking a look at adding Windows to the grub boot menu and booting Windows from grub instead of from BIOS. See the answers to [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904).

Comment: @karel Thank yo so much for your suggestions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to rename your `New Volume` to something without spaces: `NewVolume` or something else, if it is possible, and then try to repeat copying.

If not helped, then look at your `/etc/mtab` file to see what options are used to mount your `li` drive:

```
cat /etc/mtab | grep 'li'
```

If you see `ro` there in options, than you need to umount it and mount it in `rw` mode. For example, if you use an ntfs volume, you could use:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb2
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
sudo mkdir /media/li/newvolume
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /media/li/newvolume -o rw,permissions
```

where `sdXX` is your drive you could see when you run `sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop` or in GParted

You could also add it to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb2 /media/li/newvolume ntfs rw,permissions 0 0
```

Make sure, there's no other records for the same partition

Also:

- Download Windows 10 Live CD
- Load into Windows -> Device Manager  ->  Disk Drives
- Select your `New Volume` - right click -> Properties -> Policies -> Write-Caching policy
- Uncheck "Enable write caching on the device"
- Reboot into Ubuntu and check