# How to automatically mount usb flash drive at startup

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, hard-drive, flash

I need to mount usb flash drive to automatically during OS startup also tried

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /media
```

but after rebooting not able to see mounted drive please suggest.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0411:00a2 BUFFALO INC. (formerly MelCo., Inc.)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

df -h
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make hdd's mount at startup in ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-hdds-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Edit your `fstab` via

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add the line below

```
UUID=0e281f8d-1117-451d-9b1b-b07405a631bc /media auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Replace the UUID in my example above with the UUID of your partition

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdb2 | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

Note, the entry in your `fstab` doesn't mount the drive if it's not present during startup.

Comment: I have a question, If I want to mount every usb (with out specific UID)How can I change the fstab?

Comment: @H.Ghassami use `/dev/sdXX` instead of `UUID=...`

Answer (score 19):

You can use Ubuntu `Disks` utility. Open the Dash and search for `Disks`.

Select your USB key in the menu on the left, click the gears and select **Edit Mount options** :

[image]

From here simply check : **Mount at startup** :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update 

I want to use it using command line, monitor is not connected with server to do this graphically interface.

Comment: Refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/164926/338915) then.