# Automatically create share upon restart on mounted drive

Tags: mount, samba

My home server has a 2TB internal hard drive which is used as general storage and isn't part of the file system (in the sense that it is mounted at `/media/ortix/2TB Drive`).

Whenever I reboot my machine the samba shared folders I've created there are no longer shared forcing me to recreate the shares.

Is there a way to leave the shares intact whenever the server is rebooted?

Comment: What about automounting the usb on boot following [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/683314/260379) ?

Comment: @bistoco I forgot to mention that it is an internal hard drive.

Comment: well then fstab is the answer for you, look for "mounting drive automatically on fstab"

Comment: @bistoco Automounting my drive will leave the samba shares intact?

Comment: my guess is that since the drive is not mounted on boot, samba shares failed and gets droped.