# Mounting a 2nd SDD skipped during installing 20.04.01

Tags: mount, disk

When doing a clean install of 20.04.01 I forgot to mount 2nd SDD and it is not visible in Nautilus. After the system is installed its UUID is visible in `blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="External_SSD" UUID="24d8e4bc-b711-4c2e-acb8-81e4a6cc6c72" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e696099c-6423-4ea5-af07-9ed073f28e06"
```

How to mount it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utility "Disks" if you prefer a graphical interface to configure a hard drive to be mounted automatically during startup. That can also be done by correctly adding the drive to the configuration file `/etc/fstab`. The latter method is explained [in an earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683034/how-to-automatically-mount-usb-flash-drive-at-startup).

A hard drive in linux is mounted on a folder in your file system. As such, the contents of the drive becomes available when visiting that folder, which is referred to as the "mount point". When using "Disks", the utility will suggest a mount point under /mnt/.