# Mounted hdd really slow duet to how it is mounted

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

Some days ago, in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793248/problems-with-file-folder-mode) question, I explained some minor issues that I was experiencing with a HDD that I mount using the /etc/fstab file. To partially solve the issue I decided to change how I was mounting the HDD from (mounting way 1):

```
/dev/sda7 /media/data ntfs user,nosuid,exec,nodev  0  0
```

to (mounting way 2):

```
/dev/sda7 /media/data ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

Although now I have some of the problems of the other post solved, the HDD is really slow now. For instance, copying a movie from the Ubuntu hard drive to the mounted one now performs at 50kB/sec if it has been mounted as in (1) while mounting the HDD as in (2), it goes up to 
40MB/sec. This issue only affects copying between hard drives. This is, the /media/data drive can copy content within it at 40MB/sec regardless of how it is mounted.

Any idea on why this might be?

Comment: Possibly related: [ntfs-3g poor write speed](http://serverfault.com/questions/333046/ntfs-3g-poor-write-speed). Is the `sync` option essential?

Comment: I don't know. I copied this configuration from elsewhere.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `sync` option and seeing if that works for you

Comment: Taking this out not only made it go to normal speed again, but also decreased drastically the amount of buffer memory consumption .