# Need advise choosing partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Hi i am new in all of this.
My question is simple

I want to install Ubuntu in the C disk which has 279gb. My Win 10 is installed in this Drive.
D disk is the one i use it for all programs and files, music, photos etc. 
I assume Recovery F and HP_Tools G are supposed not to be modified.
I do not want to use the D disk, only the C.
I also want to fully delete Windows because i want a clean install.

Suppose i want to go back to Windows 10 is it the same process as always? plug the usb drive and install it? Because i read something about Journaling file system which linux uses a different one from windows, so i am not sure what to do, or maybe i do not understand nothing which i'ts very likely.

So how can i install Ubuntu in C? I tried but i do not fully understand the procedure because when i want to check the partition (see the picture) i can't choose it.

[image: Mi PC]

[image: Ubuntu Installer]

Comment: Since you're new to this, I just want to make sure: have you made a backup of all your important files? You should do so before changing any partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new in the Linux World but yes, i backup everything.

Comment: Please note that Linux and Windows systems have completely different ways to represent disks/partitions. On Ubuntu, your first disk is `/dev/sda`, second disk is `/dev/sdb` and so on. The first partition on the first disk is `/dev/sda1`, second partition on first disk is `/dev/sda2` and so on. On Windows the partition you install the system gets labelled `C:` and all others get subsequent letters in a random (or probably just illogic to me) order or can get reassigned any letter manually.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes i noticed that, so in /sda it is possible to install Ubuntu? only in /sda, or maybe i can erase everyting and just intall Ubuntu i the whole 750gb of the disc. Then if i want to go back to W10 i just create a 300gb partition for the OS and the rest will be "Local Disk D"
i haven't rtfm yet, but i will. 
What i really want to know is if should i keep the Recovery F and HP_Tools G partitions?

Comment: great @user68186 so in order to install Ubuntu, /sda will be completely erased and Ubuntu itself will create the partitions needed in those 320gb, right? If i want to go back to W10, will i be able to install it in /sda or as windows calls "Local disk C"? (i suppose that those 279gb from my computer will be increased if i ever go back to W10 because the other partitions (F and G) will be merged (with C)  when Ubuntu gets installed)

Comment: @user68186 Have you looked at my answer where i put a link of a photo called my partitions? There you can see my drives, and i am sure i have 2 separates hard drives, 2 physically separates, not just one. But i just asking because i am not entirely sure.
so, do you suggest to delete everything from /sda? because that recovery partition is giving me doubts, but i have never use it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a NTFS partition to install Ubuntu/Linux.

You can remove that partition and create the two required partitions for Ubuntu using the now unallocated space. You need a small swap partition (~2GB should be enough) (type: swap) and leave the rest of the space for / (root) (EXT4, /). Also tick format for the latter, the former doesn't require formating.

Comment: Remove Which partition? sda2? But can i install it in sda2? Replacing NTFS for EXT4. So if Linux can not use NTFS will i be able to use the "Local disk D" to put files, music and everything else?
And most important, how do i configure my Hard Drive to NTFS if i want to go back to Windows?

Comment: i would like to have the simplest. I mean only 2 partition from my 750gb.  but i am afraid on how to go back to W10. If you recommend, i delete the F and G partition

Comment: Yes, I meant remove that one of course -and- in the now unallocated space create the two required partitions. You should NOT write to the Windows system partition from Ubuntu. If you need to share files consider creating another partition (NTFS) for that purpose.  And you don't "configure" hard drives for NTFS or any other file type. File types are a characteristic of partitions, not drives (forget that ridiculous Windows terminology, it has no meaning outside the Microsoft ecosystem). You can at any time delete partitions and create new ones as you see fit, you never "convert"...

Comment: Being brutally honest, my only recommendation is to leave your computer alone. Clearly you don't know enough to try dual boot. And with factory installed Windows 10 and UEFI, things are a lot more complicated. Start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI (note: the website is temporarily down; check back later).

Comment: As CelticWarrior said, probably it's the best if you RTFM (read the ... manuals) first so that you have at least a rough understanding on how partitioning for Windows and for Linux works. Knowing the difference between Windows "drive letters" and physical disks and partitions as they are represented in Linux as well as knowing what file systems are is vital.

Comment: yes i know what you mean, it may sound ridiculous to "configure to NTFS", i just don't know the right terminology 
oh no, i have no problem following a tutorial and try dualboot. But i have this idea that the computer will be more fast if i have only one OS. That's why i want to erase windows and put Ubuntu. 
i just check the link you gave me (using web archive to acces it) and well it looks kind of hard

Comment: It's easier if you just want to install Ubuntu. Just choose erase all disk and install Ubuntu and the installer will do all the partitioning and formating for you. Use "Something else" like before if you want more control over the process.

Comment: ok, then if i want to reinstall W10, will it be like "always"?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The only difference will be that at some point the Windows installer will tell you there's no space left to install because it doesn't recognize EXT4 and swap partitions as valid. Just remove all (follow instructions) and the installer will proceed like it was a blank disk.

Comment: @CelticWarrior great, that's all i wanted to know. So /sda will be totally erased, C,, F, G will now be be gone and it will create one EXT4 and one Swap, (those 2 partitions). /sdb will remain as always.
Do you suggest to merge also the "D" / "/sdb" partition so instead of having 3 partitions EXT4, Swap and this one.?

Comment: @guido You'll probably want to format sdb as ext4 and use it as storage space. I'd suggest reading about fstab and mounting drives on boot. Start reading here: [How to make partitions mount at startup in ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04). Or you could use it as `/home/`, which may be a lot easier.

Comment: @wjandrea right, i have to mount it in order to be able to storage information and install programs.  Thanks for the link.
I have a doubt, take a look at this link, do i have 2 physically separates HDD or is it just one with 750gb?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBjU8.png