# Create symbolic link in the current web server document root permissions

Tags: permissions, apache2, directory, symbolic-link

I have static resources (mp3s and images) that I want to use in a website hosted on Apache virtual host with the following configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
    serverAlias myexample.loc   
    DocumentRoot /home/USER/www/yii2/web
    <Directory "/home/USER/www/yii2/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The resources are found on flash memory on a path like the following:

```
/media/USER/KINGSTON/audio
```

I have created a symbolic link for the above directory in the site's document root using `ls -s` like the following:

```
sudo ln -s /media/USER/KINGSTON/audio /home/USER/www/yii2/web
```

However, trying to access any resource leads to `403 Forbidden` error. How could I give **secure permissions** that allows the www-data user to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the permissions of the `/media/USER/KINGSTON/audio` directory? Remember that Apache needs +x on directories it traverses.

Thus `/media/`, `/media/USER`, `/media/USER/KINGSTON/` and `/media/USER/KINGSTON/audio` needs to have +x for world for www-data to be able to access it. This can be done with `sudo chmod +x /path`, for each of the directories above. If the KINGSTON device is *not* a unix filesystem, you may get into challenges there, as it does not have the traditional Unix ACLs.

Furthermore, I would probably add it as a normal mount point if it's a permanent solution. For how to do that, [have a look at this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/164926/653515)

As a short example - note that # as prompt denotes commands run as root, $ denotes normal user.

```
/tmp # mkdir foo
/tmp # chmod 754 foo
/tmp # cd foo
/tmp/foo # mkdir bar
/tmp/foo # chmod 755 bar
/tmp/foo # ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr--  3 root root  4096 Dec 24 14:24 .
drwxrwxrwt 57 root root 12288 Dec 24 14:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Dec 24 14:24 bar
# Note that the directory bar has read and execute permissions for everyone, but /tmp/foo has only read for others than group and user.
/tmp/foo # echo "foo" > bar/foo 
$ cd /tmp/foo/bar
bash: cd: /tmp/foo/bar: Permission denied
$ cat /tmp/foo/bar/foo
cat: /tmp/foo/bar/foo: Permission denied
/tmp/foo # chmod +x . #Add execute permission for world to /tmp/foo
$ cat /tmp/foo/bar/foo
foo
```

Comment: Indeed, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/217641) of the regarded question in your answer is very good easy and direct answer.