# How to set path to sdk that is in different drive than home

Tags: android, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

I was using Windows and now moved to Ubuntu 17.
I have formated the drive(NTFS > ext4) and copy the data again. Now the drive which is holding the sdk(which is copied from windows) is this `/mnt/72f9f0ae-7f8c-486b-9f5f-bc34efb74005/Tools/Android/sdk` now how I can set this path to android studio? because I'm expecting that the number `72f9f0ae-7f8c-486b-9f5f-bc34efb74005` will change each time I restart the computer. SO what is permanent way of setting the path to sdk which is not in the home drive?

Comment: I don't think `72f9f0ae-7f8c-486b-9f5f-bc34efb74005` should change - it should be the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) of the block device

Comment: ... having said that, you can mount the drive anywhere you like via your `/etc/fstab` file: see one of the many previous questions on this topic such as [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)