# How do I automount a drive using Gnome Disks?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-disk-utility

Alright, I fear this may be claimed as a duplicate, but I have yet to find a straight answer after lots of googling.
So here it is. I got this secundary hdd in my computer. I want it to mount at startup. The "User session defaults" setting don't. So I need to change it.
Except, I have no idea how to set the fstab settings. And I see no help or preset settings to aid.
The User Session default does sets everything I want except "mount at system startup", yet, other than the mount point, I have no idea how to set settings for it. And the settings that are there now, seem to give the drive a root-only restriction.
So.. I'm at a loss. Can anyone help?
[image: What settings do I input here?]

*Edited title to specify I wish for a solution using gnome disks.
*edit2: confused fdisk and fstab. corrected to fstab.

Comment: I'd rather want to figure out how to get the settings on Gnome Disks right.
But it is good to know of a terminal entry fallback.

Comment: I still wish for a proper answer from someone who understands this, so I won't post this as an actual answer, but I did eventually find this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

the setting for my drive is now:
defaults,user,rw,x-gvfs-show,dmask=000,fmask=111
And so far it seems to work as I want.

Comment: Gnome Disks is covered in the linked thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/301745). For more specific details, it (mostly) depends on the filesystem type. You could start by reading `man fstab` and `man mount` (section "Filesystem specific mount options"). If you want to make your question more specific, please edit it.