# long boot time by changing mount point for second drive

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

i have two drives, one ssd and one hdd. i have installed ubuntu on the ssd, and now i want to change the mount point of the hdd (or one of the partisions on it). i do this in disks, and its pretty straightforward. i put the new mount point under home/user/Disk2. and i also put it to mount on startup. now i have a problem; when i start the laptop, the boot time have gone from maybe 20 sec to 2-3 minutes.

why is this?

im sure its because of changing the mount point, i done it back and forth, and it always have the same effect. one thing though, if i change it back to defaults, /mnt/-longnumber-/ it first takes a super slow reboot and then it boots like it should

edit;

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
2      538MB   240GB  240GB  ext4


Model: ATA WDC WD10SPCX-21K (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                                     Flags
1      17,4kB  134MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
2      135MB   800GB   799GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
3      800GB   800GB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition          boot, esp
4      800GB   966GB   166GB   ext4
5      966GB   1000GB  34,2GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=53c1904b-c142-4fdc-82e2-73e4d201a0ba /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0986-2AB0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/48429D47429D3B20 /mnt/48429D47429D3B20 ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: I am not sure Disks assigns the correct parmeters. Often best to copy and change for your system a good example of fstab entry. What format is partition? Post this: `sudo parted -l`. And post this above also: `cat /etc/fstab`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup &  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with @oldfred 's help, i solved it. i put some default values suggested for ntfs partipations directly in the fstab, and now the boot time is back to normal. so Disks doest something wrong. I dont know which oone of these it would be nosuid,nodev,nofail or if it needed the values i put in ; uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137