# How do i show HDD partitions in "Other locations" section?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have currently dualboot Windows and Ubuntu 17.10 . There are 4 hardisk partitions that appear like this shown in image.
[image: Other locations]

Now i want to remove windows completely, repartition harddisk and use ubuntu, but want to show partitions like this only. How is it possible ?

Comment: Best to label partitions that you only want to occasionally mount. Then it will show under label, not size or UUID. Use gparted or Disks to add labels. Or if you always want partition mounted, create mount point & add to fstab. https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup  Do not keep NTFS partitions unless you have Windows or Windows repair disk, as NTFS will need chkdsk which cannot be done from Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's always a good idea to back-up before deleting or re-sizing partitions. You can use something like partimage, clonezilla or dd if your feeling brave!

1) Create a USB Gparted live image and boot to it. https://gparted.org/liveusb.php

2) Find your Windows partition in Gparted's menu, it should be NTFS.

3) Right-click on your Windows partition and choose "Delete". Select any other Windows related partitions, you may want to delete them as well.

4) Right-click on your Linux partition and choose "Resize/Move." Resize it so it takes up the rest of the now-free space on your drive.

5) Click the "Apply All Operations" button in the toolbar to perform the selected tasks.

6) Shutdown and remove the USB Gparted live image.

7) On startup your boot-loader will still have some Windows entries. To delete, open a terminal and type: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Actually my ubuntu is broken. So I am going to do fresh install along with removing wndows.