# Ubuntu boots into emergency mode in my dual-boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, disk

I installed Ubuntu 18 alongside Windows 10. I partitioned a separate drive for /, swap and the rest of it for /windows as FAT32.
Everything worked fine and I could access both OSes. Then I did two things which I'm not sure which one caused my problem:
**1-** I changed the default OS to boot from Ubuntu to my Windows boot config (I don't think this caused my problem)
**2-** I formatted that shared FAT32 drive to NTFS in Windows 10 (which was FAT32 and mounted to /windows while installing Ubuntu) .
Now when I try to boot Ubuntu, it says it is in emergency mode and throws something along the lines:

```
tpm_crb: can't request region for resource [at some address]
```

[image]

Here is what is in fstab:
[image]
What is the solution to this problem?

PS1. I disabled "fast boot" after this problem. Didn't fix it.
PS2. Machine model is Lenovo Ideapad 110 Laptop
PS3. I commented out /windows line and now it booted into Ubuntu. But how can I completely fix this problem?

Comment: What brand/model system? Some require boot parameters. Was FAT32 partition being mounted by fstab. If so, you must edit it from vfat to ntfs, or at least comment it out for now.  were you getting same errors before but system booted and it is only the fstab entry that is stopping boot. Post link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I don't know what fstab is. When I was installing ubuntu, I repartitioned a NTFS drive and made it into 3 drives (1 root, 1 swap and the remaining space into FAT32). The whole setup was working fine until I formatted that last drive to NTFS in windows. Now ubuntu can't boot

Comment: @oldfred Commenting out /windows mout worked but how can I fix this problem completely?

Comment: You need to change mount from vfat to ntfs. see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions  Essentially copying NTFS example but using your UUID & /windows mount point.