# External Hard Drive Causes System to Boot Into Emergency Mode?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, fstab

This is the entry in fstab for my external hard drive that causes the system to boot into emergency mode:

```
#UUID=0f834b1e-78a4-4b8b-9528-3b6c3f5ae37b /media/sarah/ELYSIUM btrfs defaults,space_cache,compress=zstd,autodefrag 0   0
```

What exactly causes this, and how can I auto-mount the drive with the specified options when I plug in the drive without booting into emergency mode?

I've read and understand the formatting of fstab from posts such as ([How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)) and their answers.

Should I have an entry for a removable drive in fstab, or is this only for drives to mount at boot and all others need to be mounted using `mount`?

System: Kubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Comment: You show a space after the comma after defaults, no spaces allowed. I do not mount external drives with fstab, but typically label every partition so mounted with label. I have seen where you should have the autofs or noauto option for external drives, in case drive is not available when rebooting. Often external drives do not come up to speed as fast as Ubuntu boots.

Comment: @oldfred My bad, that wasn't there in the file. So should I use autofs or noauto?

Comment: I have not used either one, but others have posted to use  autofs, often used with nfs but also suggested for any drive not permanently mounted. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266196/nfs-mount-with-fstab-vs-autofs I think noauto will just not mount, but you have to mount it yourself. https://superuser.com/questions/1038136/what-is-the-noauto-mount-flag-for  I believe defaults includes auto, so that may be a conflict. see `man mount` and `man fstab`