# My hard disk partition doesn't appear in Nautilus directly. What should I do?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, nautilus

I run Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS. I have an hard drive of 500 GB. I have 3 ext4 partitions in it. In 1st partition I have installed Ubuntu and the other 2 are for my data. Those other two partitions do not appear in Nautilus directly i.e. they do not appear in the list on the left-hand side i.e. below Home, Videos, Pictures and all. Is there anyway to do so? I always have to go to '*Other Locations*' and then access them.

Comment: Umm..sorry guys. I have four partitions and one is ubuntu, second one is swap and other two are data.

Comment: How are these partitions mounted? You can go to their directories (mount points) one by one and create bookmarks in Nautilus.

Comment: Try to mount them under /media, then they will appear in nautilus

Comment: @LeonidMew I don't think in newer Nautilus releases it would appear in the Nautilus sidebar, as OP mentioned it's hidden under "other locations".

Comment: @pomsky I have tested it, you are right, partition not appear on left side of nautilus. In nemo its fine :)

Comment: I can see them in Nautilus after bookmarking. But, I cannot see them in Jupyter Notebook. Is there anyway to mount them as the ubuntu partition is mounted so that I can access it from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bookmark those partitions for convenience. Go to the partition from '*Other Locations*' and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Then it would appear in the Nautilus sidebar.

But note that this bookmark would work only when the **partition is already mounted**. So consider making the partitions [mount automatically at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/164926/480481) too.

Comment: I can see them in Nautilus after bookmarking. But, I cannot see them in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @dhiraj Consider asking a new question for that.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer.