# My first time in emergency mode. Don't know what to do. Steps to debug

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Hello yesterday I was happy because I installed a second drive myself without annoying the people in this forum.

All was working good. Today I turned on my PC and it was in emergency mode. I don't know why...

What are the steps to Debug and to know whats happening in my case.

I run Kubuntu 19.04. (ONLY - no other system)

1 SSD & 1 HDD

Something I've done is typing

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

```
#file system mount point type options dump pass
#was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
UID=49cc34c5-f01e-4ee0-929d-ef4f06c515be  / ext4 errors=remount-ro       0     1
/swapfile none swap SW 0 0 
/dev/sdc1  /HDD  ext4  defaults 0 0
```

Thank you

Comment: First aid.Remove the line /dev/sdc1  /HDD  ext4  defaults 0 0   in /etc/fstab.  And reboot.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot @user966203

Comment: Your flash drive was probably sda or sdb & / was on the other drive, so new drive was originally seen as sdc. But on reboot it become sdb? This is why internal drives partitions should be mounted using UUID or labels, not device as device numbering can change. Just change to UUID like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like me...

I want to add this

When loading the system. You can see the logo KUBUNTU.

You can press the up arrow once and then you see what the system is actually doing at the moment.

There was a line in RED

```
Time Timed out waiting for device /dev/sdc1
```

There were another in Yellow

```
DEPEND Dependency failed for /HDD
DEPEND Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

This new insights to my problem was about to add to this post in order to give more information that could help me getting answers.

But the kind comment by @user966203 resolved my problem

If you have suggestions on how to give more accurate information in such a case please comment or answer this question.