# Installation of 18.02 fails to recongnise second drive

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, hard-drive, gparted

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 from v 16.04. After installation I am unable to see the 2TB hard-drive installed on my computer.  I have installed gparted and can see the drive.  I do not know how to configure or use gparted to be able to see/use the 2TB hard drive.  How do I make my 2TB hard drive usable in 18.02?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this an internal drive? If so you can mount using fstab, so always mounted when you reboot. You also need to give yourself ownership & permission of folders in the partition(s). See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983336 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @oldfred.  Yes, this is an internal drive.

Comment: Thanks, @oldfred. Those links provided the necessary information.  I can now see my hard-drive.