# Script to auto mount NTFS partions

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mount, nautilus

I'm using a dual-booted system with Win10. However, every time I log in I have to go and mount the partitions from Nautilus.

I've been looking through some ways to automate this at bootup but some methods are too complex. I've been through this [excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46589/922180) but it seems too complicated and also tends to use `sudo` at times.

[image: Nautilus without sudo]

I'm wondering if I can just click at a drive and mount it without `sudo`, can I do the same with a script?

Comment: `fstab` (file system table) is just a `mount` command presented differently.   I would suggest making an fstab entry, and if you don't want it to automount, then use `,noauto,user` and just enter `mount /my-ntfs/` and it'll mount on request (without `sudo` hassle too).

Comment: It really isn't complicated, it just gives multiple options. Look at the fstab section. You only need to use `sudo` once to edit the file, after that it just works. And all you need to do is edit one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/922180) has the simplest approach that I've seen. Once you're done editing the mount options a star appears on the said entry.

Editing `fstab` is also a good option but it did lead to mounting just the first entry automatically and one needed to manually mount by running `sudo mount -a`. This did mount the partitions but it also leads to `nautilus` showing available space on each partition as that of the last entry in `/etc/fstab`.