# How to add a new HDD

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive

I'm running Ubuntu as my guest OS from vmware and want to add a new HDD. so I added this

[image]

The 10 GB HDD added but I do not see it appearing in Ubuntu anywhere. I tried `sudo ls /dev/sd*` and all I got was `sda0` and `sda1`.

I tried GParted but it won't run. I tried KDE Partition manager but it errors out saying you are not the root. I tried Ubuntu's built-in disk manager and this is what it shows:

[image: ubuntu disk tool]

and here is the output of lsblk: 
[image: lsblk output]

So what should I do? How do I get the new HDD in linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)

Comment: @Graham no it's not. that question talks about mounting it at a location, mine is not even showing anywhere as if it does not even exist

Comment: Does it show when you list block devices (`lsblk`)?  (I'd then likely use `blkid` to get the detail to add the entry in the file-system table).  If it doesn't show I'd likely blame a vmware config issue on host.

Comment: @guiverc just added the lsblk output to the question.

Answer (score 2):

it turned out to be a pretty stupid thing. I read the documentation and did a little research. it seems that I needed a drive size at least 20 GB.

not sure if that's  some limitation from ubuntu or VMware. so I did that and it appeared fine as /dev/sdb and everything is working fine now.

*10GB drive just doesn't work*!