# make nautilus stop asking for password when mounting disk

Tags: command-line, 18.04, nautilus, automount

My desktop has another hard drive which I intend to use for data storage and the issue is that nautilus always asks for password when trying to mount that drive.

Same when I try and access the drive from the terminal, I get

```
ls: cannot open directory '/media/luca/Storage/': Permission denied
```

So basically, I always need to use sudo to perform file operations on this directory.

Now, is there a way to remove this restriction. How can I auto mount this drive without having to specify my password every time or having to use `sudo` every time I have to access files on this drive?

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/931617)

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thank you for the comment. The thing is it does mount it but asks me for password everytime I want to access it. How can I make it not ask for password everytime?

Comment: You can change the owner of the directory where the drive is mounted: `sudo chown -R luca:luca /media/luca/Storage/`. If you do an `ls -l` now it's probably owned by the root user.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: glad it helped! posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the owner of the directory where the drive is mounted to be your own user:

```
sudo chown -R luca:luca /media/luca/Storage/
```