# Existing Ubuntu 20.04 installation does not detect a newly added NVMe drive. BIOS is fine

Tags: 20.04, nvme

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a 256 GB, 2.5in  SSD in a system that also has a 2 TB HDD for data. Everything working fine. Added 256 GB NVMe drive. The BIOS found it correctly. SATA is set to AHCI. Ubuntu cannot find the NVMe drive. What do I do to get Ubuntu to see it. Do I need to mount it? If I do, how and what do I mount? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Psagdeo

Comment: Have you updated Firmware in NVMe drive? Many need that. Install this: `sudo apt install nvme-cli` and see if then shown: ` sudo nvme list`

Comment: Thanks.  Gparted found the drive and created a partition.  However, the owner is root and no matter what I try, I cannot change the owner and get a full access to this drive.  It is at present a blank drive that I cannot do anything with.  Please suggest a remedy.   Thanks.

Comment: What format is partition. If NTFS it will always be root, but you mount it with permissions to use it. With ext4 your have to mount giving yourselft ownership & permissions. And best to mount with fstab if internal drive, so always mounted on reboot.  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup Best not to use Disks as it does not use best parameters.