# how do I configure ubuntu to download to a usb drive

Tags: command-line, configuration, usb-drive

I'm still a noob so please excuse the simple question.

I got ubuntu 20.04 installed on a Raspberry Pi 4. The OS is installed on a 16G SD card. That don't give me any space for downloads. I have a 2T USB thumb drive I want to use for downloads.

Can anyone please help me configure ubuntu to download to that USB drive?

I'm familiar with inputing in the terminal but I don't know what command to use.

Comment: You haven't given any clues as to how you are downloading.  I use `wget` usually myself, so it goes to the $PWD or my *present working directory* meaning I have full control on where I download via where I am when I start download.  How are you downloading?  (and where do you have the 2TB device mounted?)  Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, and what application are you using to download?

Comment: In Firefox go to `Settings/Preferences/Files and Applications/Downloads` click `save files to`, and from the dropdown select your 2TB USB.

Comment: Hi. And excuse me for not replying Sooner. That's exactly what I needed. At first I wasn't seeing my USB drive but I did some further research and tried mounting the drive at boot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount the disk to /mnt/Download (You can edit /etc/fstab to let it mount every time you boot, see [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup) , make sure to add `x-systemd.automount,nofail` into mount options.)
2. `sudo chmod ugo+rw /mnt/Download`
3. `ln -s /mnt/Download /home/yous-username/Downloads`
4. You can also config the browser to directly download to /mnt/Download
   If you use a  command-line downloader (`wget`, etc.), you must first `cd` into /mnt/Download