# Invisible and not working icons on launcher bar / applications menu until I go look for them

Tags: icons, launcher

I just installed Ubuntu.

As I did have not enough space on the disk where I installed Ubuntu, I had downloaded and installed Eclipse (for Java and C++) in another disk, and everything seemed to work just fine.

Now when starting up the PC the icons I had put in the launcher bars are invisible; they are there, but they just don't work, and same for the Applications menu. But if I open the file explorer and go directly to the launchers, they appear and start working! Can anyone explain to me why and how I can fix it?

[image: Screen that show the launcher menu empty]

Comment: Do those icons work after you access the other disk? I wonder if the other disk isn't mounted when you try to use the icons from the launcher.

Comment: @mchid yes they work after I access the other disk, do you know how can I check if the other disk is correctly mounted? Thank you for answering btw!

Comment: Well, you can make sure the disk will automatically mount during startup by using the Disks application [as described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/167115).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the icons are invisible until you mount the extra disk where the applications are installed.

To make sure the disk automatically mounts at startup, open the Gnome Disks application.

Then, select drive, partition, the gear icon, "edit mount options", and then make sure "mount at system startup" is checked.

One user also mentioned to uncheck "Automatic mount options".

[You can read more about automatically mounting the disk or partition on this related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/167115).

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem