# Ubuntu (installed in SSD) is not showing Hard disk drives while windows 10 do shows them

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have SSD and HDD (500GB). I have dual boot in SSD to work things faster (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS). In windows all the Hard Disk drive are shown but in Ubuntu there is no such files are found.So I have to place all my files in Installation drive and it takes memory which causes slow functioning. Can anyone tell me why the hard disk drives are not being shown on Ubuntu as they do in windows ? Any help will be appreciated.

[lsblk -f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/due7P.png)
[lsblk log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpvFP.png)
[df -h log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKqSW.png)

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ed4cc11c-076e-47ed-8590-71f00f5468d5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=16E1-C8BC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 18. Might you mean 18.04.? Also what is a simple hard disk? How are the files taking memory?

Comment: @David I have edited the question. what do you mean How are the files taking memory?

Comment: @David I use Pycharm a lot to develop website so my PC got hanged all the time

Comment: include logs for the following commads. `lsblk` and `df -h`

Comment: @InjamulMohammadMollah I have included screenshots for logs. have a look at them

Comment: As I can see, you have not mounted the Hard disk which is `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, and `/dev/sdb3`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this ? As I am not aware of these stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)

Comment: No. It does not

Comment: Your biggest issue is that Windows is not shutting down completely. To do so try disabling fastboot in windows power settings. (i.e the setting for what happens when pressing power button) That may not be enough, to insure complete shutdown use and hold the power button down until windowss shuts down. Then boot to ubuntu, open file manager > locations > double click on your data drive. (assuming you haven't edited your fstab which is not needed for access, only for automount which is unnessasary

Comment: @doug I will try and will let you know

Comment: still HDD is not visible

Comment: When you open Nautilus & open other locations in the sidebar you don't see your data hdd ( and windows drive?

Comment: No, I don't see my HDD. I only see SSD drives (Windows drive and Ubuntu installed drive)

Comment: Interesting. I have same set up, can always see but can't write to data drive if it was accessed in windows & windows wasn't completely shut down. I'd  copy out anything you want to save from it in windows, then format it to ntfs, shutdown windows completely & see..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121028/discussion-between-nasir-hussain-and-doug).

Comment: You first have to make sure Windows has shutdown without the hibernation flag set on all your NTFS partitions. And Windows, with updates, will turn fast start up back on setting hibernation flag. Details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation