# How to create drives as in Windows for Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I cant seem to find drives like E or D, in ubuntu, every folder or file get saved in the desktop itself. Please help

Comment: You can create your own "drives" which really are partitions And you can give them labels or mount using a name you assign, so better idea of E: drive is really the "backup" partition. Data should normally be saved in /home and the folders there, not to desktop. https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Linux doesn't work like windoze with drive letters like C,D,E etc. [This reference](https://linuxhint.com/find_files_on_ubuntu/) might help explain.

Comment: You *could* create partitions, but that's a horrible idea if your only purpose for doing so is organization. Over-partitioning only creates rigid artificial limitations on how your space can be used.  Folders are better for this purpose. You can even name a folder "D" and "E" if you are really insistent on using those designations for some reason.

Comment: It's also unclear what you are even asking.  Are you just trying to find the path for partitions or volumes that already exist in Windows that Windows refers to as D and E? The most user friendly way to determine the path is to open the "Disks" application, choose the disk or partition, and it will tell you the path where the partition or volume is mounted in your filesystem

Comment: The filesystem uses mount points instead of an individual filesystem for each drive. In unix/linux, it is often said that "everything is a file" and this is a good example. Device names are usually `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` etc.  Your main drive (like windows drive C: or `/dev/sda1`) is mounted at the mount point `/` and you can add an additional drive (like windows drive D: or `/dev/sda2`), like a branch off of a tree, at a different mount point under this drive like at `/media/abhay/drivename/`, for example, and everything on that drive would be in a file under this mount point.

Comment: Long story short, the device names are not listed in the file system. Only the mount point of each device (the folder at which each drive exists) is listed.

Comment: Please update your question with what you want to achieve, and why.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Unix has the concept of a strictly hierarchical file system, with `/` as the root of the file system - and everything under that, even if it's a different physical drive or a network file system.

User's files are *supposed* to be in `/home/username`, or equivalent. The home directory contains *everything* personalized to a user, such as documents, configuration files, programs for that user and so forth.

Create directories in your home directory to organize things the way you prefer, but you should view `/home/username` as the *only* place to store files.

This incidentally makes backups easy; if you only care about user data, backup `/home/` and ignore the rest of the system.

Comment: Most likely, OP has a single, large partition, and wants to break it into smaller ones, which is certainly possible in Ubuntu. *You can't* really does not answer that question.

Comment: Given that he references that everything gets saved on the desktop, I don't find this reasonable, and thus an answer explaining how the Unix file system is built up is on topic. I may very well be wrong, but as the question stands I believe this to be a at least *somewhat* useful answer :)

Comment: I think it's very unclear what OP is asking so it may have been premature to answer the question. It seems like OP might be asking how to create partitions. But they could also be asking how to find a completely different hard drive or partition that Windows calls D and/or E.  They might even be asking how to save files somewhere else. The question lacks specifics and details to understand what is the actual problem faced by the OP