# Not able to download files to a folder on hdd

Tags: hard-drive, downloads

My laptop has 256gb SSD and 1tb HDD. I recently installed Ubuntu on SSD. My home folder is on SSD. Now, when I am downloading a file and trying to save it to a folder on hdd, it doesnt get downloaded. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using dual boot? and are you using different file systems for hdd or ssd eg: ext4 and  ntfs ?

Comment: You can move the files from the Downloads folder to their final destination on the SSD. Add the Ubuntu version you are using (the command `lsb_release -a` can give this information).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)