# Windows like partion in Ubntu22.04

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I am new to Linux. Yesterday i have installed ubuntu 22.04 and during the partition I made **"/personal"** with 300GB space but after installation, it seems this drive is in root and I do not have read/write permission to this derive and I am unable to give permission to use other than root. Is there any way to move this partition to home or give full permission?
Basically, i want to have windows drive systems like c, d,e drives.

Comment: The problem is likely permissions and/or ownership on the mount point. If you open a terminal and do `ls -l` on the location, it will tell you who owns it and what the permissions are. Please edit your question and include this information. Don't post it in comments, or add a screenshot. Copy and paste the information.

Comment: I’m sure it’s possible - but, (and I know it’s not your question) please consider if you really want to do this. Linux is different from windows; if you try to make it as windows-like as possible, it won’t be the same and you’ll probably be left thinking it’s not as good just because it isn’t the same. When I moved from Win to Ubuntu, I deliberately didn’t make it emulate windows - and I now hugely prefer Ubuntu. There really isn’t any advantage to having c /d / e drives etc, once you’re used to the unified file system of Linux.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/138551

Answer (score 1):

That is default behaviour

You do a

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /personal
```

(`$USER` will magically be changed to the user you used to issue this command; the user needs to be your admin user; if you want another user than your admin user type the actual username instead of `$USER`)

and you own the partition. If you need more than 1 user change the 2nd $USER to a group those users all belong and all those users can use it.

> Basically, i want to have windows drive systems like c, d,e drives.

Not possible. You could make a mountpoint with name c but that to most of use is a degression. We name our partitions with user friendly names. I would ask to get used to how things are done in Linux and I guarantee you will like it soon too :)

Everything in Linux also has a place something belongs to.
If you want to mount fixed harddisks with windows partitions you do that in `/mnt` using `/etc/fstab`. Removables automatically mount in `/media`.

Mounting windows partitions: [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)