# I seem to have completely messed up my filesystem

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem

Ubuntu 22.04 on a lenovo ThinkPad W520. I #think# I have an external disc mounted on /media/claus and the terminal finds it. In my sidepane though the "500 GB Volume" symbol that should represent it gives me a "Folder is empty".

Trying to sort this out, I came upon some strange things in my system. "mount" tells me sda5 has been linked twice, once on "/" and once on /var/snap/firefox... Sounds strange to me.

Then, sda 1 is mounted on /boot/efi and when I try to go there with a sudo cd I get "command not found" "cd is a shell built-in command, it cannot be run directly" - whatever that means.

My SD card is mounted on /media/claus and works, but it's name in teh terminal is deb4033-6c02- and 20 more characters ending in 1 and other than that "1" identical to another drive mounted here, empty. This card figures as "249GB Volume" in my sidepane.

Then, there's sdb mounted on /media/claus where it appears as "ExternMusic" which is just what I wanted but although I can access it through the terminal, and my DAW finds it as well, it does not appear in my desktop's sidepanel where I shuld expect it.
I've got the "Linux Command Line", Second Internet Edition from 2013 but nothing I find there helps me getting out of this.

Where can I go to find help part from here? I tried to backup especially my music before updating to 22, that's where I suspect I have messed things up completely. Pleas help.

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8031516k,nr_inodes=2007879,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1613964k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=17312)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2785.snap on /snap/core18/2785 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2812.snap on /snap/core18/2812 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2105.snap on /snap/core20/2105 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2182.snap on /snap/core20/2182 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1033.snap on /snap/core22/1033 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_1122.snap on /snap/core22/1122 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3687.snap on /snap/firefox/3687 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3836.snap on /snap/firefox/3836 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_140.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_143.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_120.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/120 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap on /snap/gnome-42-2204/141 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_638.snap on /snap/snap-store/638 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap on /snap/snap-store/959 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_19457.snap on /snap/snapd/19457 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_20671.snap on /snap/snapd/20671 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_57.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_83.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_3078.snap on /snap/vlc/3078 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda5 on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_3721.snap on /snap/vlc/3721 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1613960k,nr_inodes=403490,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1613964k,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/claus/deb4033b-6c02-4efc-af05-c7fc4b8473e51 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb on /media/claus/6df32c8d-5c37-445d-b973-e3b887151062 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
claus@StudioBox:~$
```

Comment: Regarding this: sudo cd I get "command not found" "cd is a shell built-in command, it cannot be run directly"
The whole point of cd is to change the working directory of the current process. Spawning a subshell (via sudo or other means) to do a cd is pointless. If it worked, it would change the working directory of the subshell which would then exit and you would be back to where you were before. If you want a root shell in another directory, start that shell first (e.g. sudo bash) and then cd inside that shell.

Comment: Just use cd to go there without sudo and then if you get permission denied for trying to do stuff after that like for ls or whatever, then use sudo for that.

Comment: "and once on /var/snap/firefox... Sounds strange to me": That is a bind mount

Comment: Ok thanks but these are minor problems that only mentioned because I thought may have something to do with the main concern which is, what is that funny ghost second link to my SD Card and why is the "ExternMusic" not visible in my Gnome desktop? What can I do in order to have the drives and partitions mirrored in my sidepane when I open a "Files" window? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] with `mount` and look in `udisksctl dump` for anything that is unexpected

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what that means ... how do I "edit with mount" and where do I find udisksctl dump? Sorry

Comment: Please click [edit] in my comment or your question and paste the output of `mount` after you type that into a terminal. You can also type the other command into the terminal, but the output is very long

Comment: ok I hope I did it right now ...

Comment: Your output doesn't show `/media/claus` or `sdb`. Furthermore, udisks will always mount it in a ***subfolder*** of `/media/claus`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)

Comment: oh no please forgive me, I was sitting at zthe wrong machine ... I'm such a moron, I'll go back now

Comment: Your drive is mounted properly at `/media/claus/6df32c8d-5c37-445d-b973-e3b887151062` using udisks. It seems that nautilus (GNOME Files) might not show internal drives, so you will need to click "+ Other Locations

Comment: the other link to an 11yr old question you gave me helped ... I may be on my way now, thanks a lot! Do you see any strange things in my mount thing? I found out now that what I thought was on my external music disc is in fact in a partition on the boot disc. Any dangers in sight?

Comment: In the link, you seem to be using the udisks/GUI option. The other option will mount the partition earlier at boot and at a location you can specify, but it won't solve the problem of it not showing up in Files. It is not on your boot disk. /dev/sda is your boot disk. /dev/sdb is another disk.